# What is difference between Magento validation classes validate-number and validate-digit

Tags: magento

Suppose we have following form field.

```
$fieldset->addField('sort_order', 'text', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('look')->__('Sort Order'),
          'class'     => 'required-entry validate-number',
          'required'  => true,      
          'name'      => 'sort_order'));
```

.

```
$fieldset->addField('sort_order', 'text', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('look')->__('Sort Order'),
          'class'     => 'required-entry validate-digits',
          'required'  => true,      
          'name'      => 'sort_order'));
```

What is the difference between above two validation classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difference between Magento validation classes validate-number and validate-digit

validate-number will accept decimal numbers also like 10.3

But validate-digit will accept numbers without decimals like 10

Answer (score 8):

validate-number`[Accept also decimal number]`

Please enter a valid number in this field

validate-digits`[Accept only digit without decimal]`

Please use numbers only in this field. please avoid spaces or other characters such as dots or commas

**There are many more validation classes you can assign and I list them here as a reference.**

validate-select

Please select an option

required-entry

This is a required field

validate-alpha

Please use letters only (a-z or A-Z) in this field.

validate-code

Please use only letters (a-z), numbers (0-9) or underscore(_) in this field, first character should be a letter.

validate-alphanum

Please use only letters (a-z or A-Z) or numbers (0-9) only in this field. No spaces or other characters are allowed

validate-street

Please use only letters (a-z or A-Z) or numbers (0-9) or spaces and # only in this field

validate-phoneStrict

Please enter a valid phone number. For example (123) 456-7890 or 123-456-7890

validate-phoneLax

Please enter a valid phone number. For example (123) 456-7890 or 123-456-7890

validate-fax

Please enter a valid fax number. For example (123) 456-7890 or 123-456-7890

validate-date

Please enter a valid date

validate-email

Please enter a valid email address. For example johndoe@domain.com.

validate-emailSender

Please use only letters (a-z or A-Z), numbers (0-9) , underscore(_) or spaces in this field.

validate-password

Please enter 6 or more characters. Leading or trailing spaces will be ignored

validate-admin-password

Please enter 7 or more characters. Password should contain both numeric and alphabetic characters

validate-cpassword

Please make sure your passwords match

validate-url

Please enter a valid URL. http:// is required

validate-clean-url

Please enter a valid URL. For example http://www.example.com or www.example.com

validate-identifier

Please enter a valid Identifier. For example example-page, example-page.html or anotherlevel/example-page

validate-xml-identifier

Please enter a valid XML-identifier. For example something_1, block5, id-4

validate-ssn

Please enter a valid social security number. For example 123-45-6789

validate-zip

Please enter a valid zip code. For example 90602 or 90602-1234

validate-zip-international

Please enter a valid zip code

validate-date-au

Please use this date format: dd/mm/yyyy. For example 17/03/2006 for the 17th of March, 2006

validate-currency-dollar

Please enter a valid $ amount. For example $100.00

validate-one-required

Please select one of the above options.

validate-one-required-by-name

Please select one of the options.

validate-not-negative-number

Please enter a valid number in this field

validate-state

Please select State/Province

validate-new-password

Please enter 6 or more characters. Leading or trailing spaces will be ignored

validate-greater-than-zero

Please enter a number greater than 0 in this field

validate-zero-or-greater

Please enter a number 0 or greater in this field

validate-cc-number

Please enter a valid credit card number.

validate-cc-type

Credit card number doesn\’t match credit card type

validate-cc-type-select

Card type doesn\’t match credit card number

validate-cc-exp

Incorrect credit card expiration date

validate-cc-cvn

Please enter a valid credit card verification number.

validate-data

Please use only letters (a-z or A-Z), numbers (0-9) or underscore(_) in this field, first character should be a letter.

validate-css-length

Please input a valid CSS-length. For example 100px or 77pt or 20em or .5ex or 50%

validate-length

Maximum length exceeded

Answer (score 0):

validate-number can accept any valid number (i.e. int or float).

while validate-digit accepts numbers only.

It is clear from error message of class also.

**validate-digits**

Please use numbers only in this field. please avoid spaces or other characters such as dots or commas.

**validate-number**

Please enter a valid number in this field.